# What kind of consent do I need to implement if I want to access user's email address?

Tags: actions-on-google

We are trying to implement a google home action and it needs access to customer's email.
I can see the documentation on this page mentioned we need to have explicit consent from the user. https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies
Just wondering what sort of consent do we need to implement in order to get customer's email?

Can I please get a sample consent?

Thanks,
Yihan

Comment: to access the user email in my app (it's quite old), I had to implement account linking, therefore I think this is enough to get the user's content but I'm not certain as of today

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) in some form. If you have an existing service that gets their email address, you need to link the Action to the account they have established on your service already.

If you don't have an existing service, you can take advantage of [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in), which is a streamlined way you can get permission to access their Google Profile and, if they have one, their registered email address.